# Three OS in one system

Tags: 13.10, windows-7, chromeos

I have been using Ubuntu and Windows, which are installed side by side for about 2 and a half year by now(although I hardly open Windows) and I've had my Ups and Downs.
But now I'm trying to install another OS(CHROME OS) along with them on a third partition.
Will it pose any problem for my Current OSs.
That is should I do it or not.

Comment: no it should not pose any problem,

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't pose any real threat IF you do it right. As long as you use a separate partition for everything, and don't share a boot partition, you can get it working fine, but unless you are quite confident I would try it in a Virtualbox first.